# How to force game to window mode and to fullscreen

Tags: c#, fullscreen

Is there a easy way to force a game like I don't know DayZ from Fullscreen to Windowmode programmatically. So i have a c# program, that can minimize, maximize, close any game, but when i send resolution information to DayZ(Fullscreen), nothing happens. When i did it to while it is window mode, the size changes like i want.

Now i want to add a function, that a game which is fullscreen forces this game to windowmode, and when it is windowmode it should force it to fullscreen.

```
private void btnWindowSize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
        if (lstProcess.SelectedItem == null)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("");
            return;

        }

            int x = Convert.ToInt16(txtX.Text);
            int y = Convert.ToInt16(txtY.Text);
            Process[] pro = Process.GetProcesses();
            foreach (Process proc2 in pro)
            {
                if (proc2.MainWindowTitle == lstProcess.SelectedItem.ToString())
                {


                    hWnd = Process.GetProcessById(proc2.Id).MainWindowHandle;

                }
            }

            

            MoveWindow(hWnd, 0, 0, x, y, true);
            txtX.Text = txtY.Text = "";
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("");
        }
```

Is there any way to realize this in C#?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem by myself: It could be solved by doing the same to normal

```
form("ShowWindowAsync(hWnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL);"),
```

…and then I could change the size.